# Convert timestamp to an array of accumulative seconds

Tags: pandas

Hello I got a time stamp that I converted to this :

```
x = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S')

1900-01-01 09:48:42
1900-01-01 09:48:43
1900-01-01 09:48:44
1900-01-01 09:48:45
1900-01-01 09:48:46
1900-01-01 09:48:47
```

Now, I want to be able to retrieve and accumulate the seconds in an array, like this:

```
1 
2 
3 
4 
5
6
```

More info.

```
 x.dtype
    dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) with subtract first value with [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) and add `1`:

```
x = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])
#alternative
#x = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S')

a = x.sub(x.iat[0]).dt.total_seconds().astype(int) + 1
print (a)
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
5    6
Name: Time, dtype: int32
```

Comment: I get KeyError : 0 :'(

Comment: @falo8056 - Can you test [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html) ?